# Python string formatting with dict

Tags: python

I am fairly new to python and with all the searching I have done thus far I am unable to find an answer.  If this has been answered please point me in the right direction.  Here are the details:

I have the following counter:

```
Counter({'storage': 3, 'control': 1})
```

The formatting is as follows:

```
print "Duplicate IP, {0}, found on {1} nodes.".format(a," and ".join("%s %s" % (c,n) for n,c in dict(counter).items()))
```

which yields:

```
Duplicate IP, 192.168.56.20, found on 1 control and 3 storage.
```

Is there a way to enhance this such that if the count is 1 the '1' is not displayed? i.e:

```
Duplicate IP, 192.168.56.20, found on control and 3 storage nodes.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
print "Duplicate IP, {0}, found on {1} nodes.".format(a," and ".join("%s %s" % (c if c > 1 else '',n) for n,c in dict(counter).items()))
```

appending empty string if c is not greater than 1